# Can't get filtering to work properly with AdvancedCollectionView coupled with dynamically generated UI in MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I have an issue that's been causing me to bang my head against my desk for the past few days.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is generate two seperate lists of checkboxes corresponding to two properties of a class (Manufacturer and Category) and filter them depending on what the user checks.

What I've done is create two advancedcollectionviews corresponding to each property and filled them with their respective objects. I've created filters to filter each view based off the users selection but no matter what I do the behavior is SUPER inconsistent to where I can't figure out where to trace the problem back to.

What should happen is if the user selects a Manufacture the Category list should filter out Categories that don't include the selected Manufacturer and vice-versa. So far the only checkboxes that work this way are those generated for the Accessory Category.

Below is a video of the behavior I'm seeing. In the first part of the video you can see how it **should** work when using the Accessory Category and Microsoft Manufacturer but as the video progresses and I attempt different combinations you can see the strange but random behavior of the rest of the options.

https://youtu.be/atnmh5PdFeM

What I just can't figure out is why it works **PERFECTLY** and as I intended for the one Category/Manufacturer but not any of the others. The UI is all dynamically generated, the objects that populate the lists are all of the same type and the data is all in the same format, all of the lists generate properly. I'm at a real loss and I'm really hoping for some outside perspective!

Here is some of the relevant code:

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="#FF1B1B1B">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="470">
            <TextBlock Text="Product Catalog" FontSize="28" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" Margin="5"/>
            <Button x:Name="AddCustomerButton"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Clear All Filters" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="60" Background="#FF007ACC" Margin="15" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" />
            <ScrollViewer  Margin="5,5,0,5" Height="115" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="#FF575454">
                <StackPanel Height="146" Width="435">
                    <TextBlock Text="Category:" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"/>
                    <ListView x:Name="CategoryList" ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryCheckboxes}" >
                        <ListView.ItemsPanel >
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" Width="435"  />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <CheckBox Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedCategory, Mode=TwoWay}"  >
                                    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Checked">
                                            <core:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding ElementName=CategoryList,  Path=DataContext.CheckCategory}" />
                                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Unchecked">
                                            <core:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding ElementName=CategoryList,  Path=DataContext.UncheckCategory}" />
                                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}"  Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"/>
                                </CheckBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>

            <ScrollViewer Margin="5,5,0,5" Height="200" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="#FF575454">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Manufacturer:" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"/>
                    <ListView x:Name="ManufacturerList" ItemsSource="{Binding ManufacturerCheckboxes}">
                        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"  Width="435" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <CheckBox Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedMfg, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Checked">
                                            <core:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding ElementName=ManufacturerList,  Path=DataContext.CheckManufacterer}" />
                                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Unchecked">
                                            <core:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding ElementName=ManufacturerList,  Path=DataContext.UncheckManufacterer}" />
                                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Manufacturer}"  Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"/>
                                </CheckBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="3">
            <TextBlock Text="Products" FontSize="28" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" Margin="5"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="Search: " FontSize="24" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" Width="86" Margin="3"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="SearchTextBoxt" TextChanged="SearchTextBoxt_TextChanged" Width="725" Margin="3" TextChanging="SearchTextBoxt_TextChanging"/>
            </StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind pcvm.ProductCatalog}"  Width="837" Margin="5" Height="728">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Product">
                    <controls:Expander x:Name="Expander1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,10"
                                       BorderBrush="Bisque"
                                       Header="{Binding Name}"
                                       IsExpanded="False" Width="810" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD">
                        <Grid Height="auto" Background="#FF272727" Width="805" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="DimGray">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="auto">
                                <StackPanel Width="275" Height="auto">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Manufacturer}" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" FontSize="24" Height="auto" Margin="3"/>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Margin="3" Height="151"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" FontSize="24" Height="auto" Margin="3" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Width="522">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Height="auto" Margin="2"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" FontSize="16" Height="auto" Margin="3" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Processor}" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" Height="auto" Margin="5,8,5,5"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RAM}" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" Height="auto" Margin="5"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HDDCap}" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" Height="auto" Margin="5"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding GPU}" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" Height="auto" Margin="5"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Display}" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" Height="auto" Margin="5"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </controls:Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>`
```

C# VM:

```
public class ProductCatalogViewModel 
{
    public enum FilterTypes
    {
        Category, Manufacterer
    }
    public AdvancedCollectionView ProductCatalog { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public AdvancedCollectionView ManufacturerCheckboxes { get; set; }
    public AdvancedCollectionView CategoryCheckboxes { get; set; }
    public AdvancedCollectionView CheckBoxesCollectionView { get; set; }

    private List<string> _searchFilters;
    private string searchParam = "";
    private bool _mfgSeclected, _categorySelected, _subCategorySelected = false;
    private string _mfgFilter, _categoryFilter, _subCategoryFilter;
    public ProductCatalogProduct selectedMfgCheckbox { get; set; }
    public ProductCatalogProduct selectedCatCheckbox { get; set; }


    public ICommand CheckCategory { get; set; }
    public ICommand UncheckCategory { get; set; }
    public ICommand CheckManufacterer { get; set; }
    public ICommand UncheckManufacterer { get; set; }


    public ProductCatalogViewModel()
    {
        Products = (DataManager._productDatabase);
        ProductCatalog = new AdvancedCollectionView(Products);
        GenerateCheckBoxLists();
        CheckCategory = new RelayCommand<ProductCatalogProduct>(CheckCategoryFilter);
        UncheckCategory = new RelayCommand<ProductCatalogProduct>(UncheckCategoryFilter);
        CheckManufacterer = new RelayCommand<ProductCatalogProduct>(CheckManufacturerFilter);
        UncheckManufacterer = new RelayCommand<ProductCatalogProduct>(UncheckManufacturerFilter);

    }

    private void GenerateCheckBoxLists() //Generates the object collections that will represent the filter checkboxes in the View
    {
        ManufacturerCheckboxes = new AdvancedCollectionView(new ObservableCollection<ProductCatalogProduct>());
        ManufacturerCheckboxes = GenerateDistinctList(ProductCatalog, ProductComparer.ListTypes.Manufacturer);

        foreach (ProductCatalogProduct mfgCheckBoxItem in ManufacturerCheckboxes)
        {
            foreach (Product product in Products)
            {
                if (mfgCheckBoxItem.Manufacturer == product.Manufacturer && !mfgCheckBoxItem.CategoriesWithSameManufacterer.Contains(product.Category) )
                {
                    mfgCheckBoxItem.CategoriesWithSameManufacterer.Add(product.Category);
                }
            }
        }

        CategoryCheckboxes = new AdvancedCollectionView(new ObservableCollection<ProductCatalogProduct>());
        CategoryCheckboxes = GenerateDistinctList(ProductCatalog, ProductComparer.ListTypes.Category);

        foreach (ProductCatalogProduct catCheckBoxItem in CategoryCheckboxes)
        {
            foreach (Product product in Products)
            {
                if (catCheckBoxItem.Category == product.Category && !catCheckBoxItem.ManufacturersWithSameCategory.Contains(product.Manufacturer))
                {
                    catCheckBoxItem.ManufacturersWithSameCategory.Add(product.Manufacturer);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private AdvancedCollectionView GenerateDistinctList(AdvancedCollectionView viewToFilter, ProductComparer.ListTypes list)
    {

                AdvancedCollectionView newACV = new AdvancedCollectionView(new ObservableCollection<ProductCatalogProduct>());
                List<Product> tempList = new List<Product>();
        foreach (Product pcp in viewToFilter)
        {
            tempList.Add(pcp);
        }
                IEnumerable<Product> NoDuplicatesInitialCat = tempList.Distinct(new ProductComparer(list));
                foreach (var p in NoDuplicatesInitialCat)
                {
            ProductCatalogProduct pCP = new ProductCatalogProduct(p);
                    newACV.Add(pCP);
                }

        return newACV;


    }

    private void UncheckAllCategories()
    {
        CategoryCheckboxes.ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
 (x as ProductCatalogProduct).UncheckCategory();

        });
    }
    private void UncheckAllManufacterers()
    {
        ManufacturerCheckboxes.ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {

                (x as ProductCatalogProduct).UncheckMfg();

        });
    }


    public void CheckCategoryFilter(ProductCatalogProduct product)
    {
        if (selectedCatCheckbox != null)
        {
            selectedCatCheckbox.UncheckCategory();
            selectedCatCheckbox = null;
        }
        _categoryFilter = product.Category;
        FilterButtons(FilterTypes.Category);
        UncheckAllCategories();
        selectedCatCheckbox = product;
        if (selectedMfgCheckbox != null)
        {
            selectedMfgCheckbox.CheckMfg();
        }
        selectedCatCheckbox.CheckCategory();
       // ExecuteProductFilter();          
    }

    public void UncheckCategoryFilter(ProductCatalogProduct product)
    {
        if (selectedCatCheckbox != null)
        {
            selectedCatCheckbox.UncheckCategory();
            selectedCatCheckbox = null;
        }
        _categorySelected = false;
        _categoryFilter = String.Empty;
        ManufacturerCheckboxes.Filter = null;
        if (selectedMfgCheckbox != null)
        {

            selectedMfgCheckbox.CheckMfg();
        }
       // ExecuteProductFilter();
    }

    public void CheckManufacturerFilter(ProductCatalogProduct product)
    {
        if (selectedMfgCheckbox != null)
        {
            selectedMfgCheckbox.UncheckCategory();
            selectedMfgCheckbox = null;
        }
        _mfgFilter = product.Manufacturer;
        FilterButtons(FilterTypes.Manufacterer);
        UncheckAllManufacterers();
        selectedMfgCheckbox = product;
        if (selectedCatCheckbox != null)
        {
            selectedCatCheckbox.CheckMfg();
        }
        selectedMfgCheckbox.CheckMfg();
        //ExecuteProductFilter();
    }

    public void UncheckManufacturerFilter(ProductCatalogProduct product)
    {
        if (selectedMfgCheckbox != null)
        {
            selectedMfgCheckbox.UncheckCategory();
            selectedMfgCheckbox = null;
        }
        _mfgSeclected = false;
        _mfgFilter = String.Empty;
        CategoryCheckboxes.Filter = null;
        if (selectedCatCheckbox != null)
        {
            selectedCatCheckbox.CheckMfg();
        }
        //ExecuteProductFilter();
    }



    private List<Predicate<Product>> _criteria = new List<Predicate<Product>>();




    private bool dynamic_Filter(object item)
    {
        Product p = item as Product;
        bool isIn = true;
        if (_criteria.Count() == 0)
            return isIn;
        isIn = _criteria.TrueForAll(x => x(p));

        return isIn;
    }


    private void FilterButtons(FilterTypes filterSelected)
    {

        switch (filterSelected)
        {
            case FilterTypes.Category:

                ManufacturerCheckboxes.Filter = null;
                ManufacturerCheckboxes.Filter = x => (x as ProductCatalogProduct).CategoriesWithSameManufacterer.Contains(_categoryFilter);
                break;
            case FilterTypes.Manufacterer:
                CategoryCheckboxes.Filter = null;
                CategoryCheckboxes.Filter = x => (x as ProductCatalogProduct).ManufacturersWithSameCategory.Contains(_mfgFilter);
                break;
        }



    }




    private void ExecuteProductFilter()
    {

        ProductCatalog.Filter = null;

        _criteria.Clear();

        if (_categorySelected)
        {
            _criteria.Add(new Predicate<Product>(x => x.Category.Contains(_categoryFilter)));
        }
        if (_subCategorySelected)
        {
            _criteria.Add(new Predicate<Product>(x => x.SubCategory.Contains(_subCategoryFilter)));
        }
        if (_mfgSeclected)
        {
            _criteria.Add(new Predicate<Product>(x => x.Manufacturer.Contains(_mfgFilter)));
        }

        ProductCatalog.Filter = dynamic_Filter;
    }



    public void FilterProductDatabase(string searchParameters) //filters the advancedcollectionview using the SearchFilter method
    {
        searchParam = searchParameters;
        ProductCatalog.Filter = SearchFilter;
    }

    private bool SearchFilter(object item) //Filters each object in the advancedcollectionview based on user input into a textbox
    {


        Product p = item as Product;
        string searchTerms = "";
        searchTerms = p.Manufacturer + " " + p.Category + " " + p.SubCategory;
        if (searchTerms.Contains(searchParam))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
    {
        public enum ListTypes
        {
            Manufacturer, Category, Subcategory
        }

        public ListTypes lists;

        public ProductComparer(ListTypes listToFill)
        {

            lists = listToFill;

        }

        // Products are equal if their names and product numbers are equal.
        public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
        {

            switch (lists)
            {
                case ListTypes.Category:
                    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
                    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y.Manufacturer, null))
                        return false;
                    return x.Category == y.Category;

                case ListTypes.Manufacturer:
                    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
                    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y.Manufacturer, null))
                        return false;
                    return x.Manufacturer == y.Manufacturer;

                case ListTypes.Subcategory:
                    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
                    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y.Manufacturer, null))
                        return false;
                    return x.SubCategory == y.SubCategory;
            }
            return false;
        }

        // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
        // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

        public int GetHashCode(Product product)
        {
            switch (lists)
            {
                case ListTypes.Category:
                    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(product, null)) return 0;
                    int hashProductCategory = product.Category == null ? 0 : product.Category.GetHashCode();
                    return hashProductCategory;

                case ListTypes.Manufacturer:
                    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(product, null)) return 0;
                    int hashProductManufacturer = product.Manufacturer == null ? 0 : product.Manufacturer.GetHashCode();
                    return hashProductManufacturer;

                case ListTypes.Subcategory:
                    //Check whether the object is null
                    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(product, null)) return 0;

                    //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
                    int hashProductSubCategory = product.SubCategory == null ? 0 : product.SubCategory.GetHashCode();

                    //Calculate the hash code for the product.
                    return hashProductSubCategory;

            }
            return 0;
        }


    }
}`
```

Data Model:

```
public  class ProductCatalogProduct : Product, INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    private bool _isCheckedCategory;
    public bool IsCheckedCategory
    {
        get { return _isCheckedCategory; }
        set { _isCheckedCategory = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsCheckedCategory"); }
    }

    private bool _isCheckedMfg;
    public bool IsCheckedMfg
    {
        get { return _isCheckedMfg; }
        set { _isCheckedMfg = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsCheckedMfg"); }
    }
    public ProductCatalogProduct(Product productBase)
    {
        Manufacturer = productBase.Manufacturer;
        Category = productBase.Category;
        Price = productBase.Price;
        ManufacturersWithSameCategory = new List<string>();
        CategoriesWithSameManufacterer = new List<string>();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public List<string> ManufacturersWithSameCategory { get; set; }
    public List<string> CategoriesWithSameManufacterer { get; set; }

    public void UncheckAll()
    {
        IsCheckedCategory = false;
        IsCheckedMfg = false;
    }

    public void CheckAll()
    {
        IsCheckedCategory = true;
        IsCheckedMfg = true;
    }

    public void CheckCategory()
    {
        IsCheckedCategory = true;
    }

    public void UncheckCategory()
    {
        IsCheckedCategory = false;
    }

    public void CheckMfg()
    {
        IsCheckedMfg = true;
    }

    public void UncheckMfg()
    {
        IsCheckedMfg = false;
    }

    public bool GetCategoryChecked()
    {
        return IsCheckedCategory;
    }

    public bool GetMfgChecked()
    {
        return IsCheckedMfg;
    }
}`
```

Comment: I ended up solving the issue with a few lists/collections by just removing/adding items between them, but the performance and transitions suck compared to using a filter so I'd still appreciate any input anyone might have.

I also noticed that the buttons that do work in the posted question are populated by items in the [0] position within their collections which I'm sure helps find the issue but I still don't know what that tells me about the problem.